# How to repopulate an arrayadapter when database is modified in a different activity?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I am working on an array adapter which uses a master detail flow layout in order to show list of items that are stored within the apps database.

From this activity/fragment, I call a different activity to add a new record to the database. When the new record is added, this activity is finished and the user is returned to the master detail flow layout.

I then want this view to be shown with the updated database that was created in the new activity. I'm not 100% sure what would be the best way to implement this. I was thinking of in the onResume method, I call a function that repopulates the array adapter with the new data but this seems like the way wrong way as it would always repopulate even if no data was changed in the database.

Comment: Are you using a ContentProvider with your database or are you working with the database directly?

Comment: Working with the database directly

Comment: Ah - bummer.  I was going to say with a ContentProvider, you could register a ContentObserver to be notified on a Uri level when something has changed.

Comment: The startActivityForResult and onActivityResult is the best approach you can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the activity for adding items using `startActivityForResult()`
and implement the callback `onActivityResult()` in the list activity.

You can repopulate the list items in the `onActivityResult()` in case there was a successfully added element to the database.

See this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

For example in listActivity

```
private void addItem(){
    ...
    startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_REQUEST);
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ADD_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // here you can repopulate the list
    }
}
```

and the addItem activity

```
private void addingItem(){
    ...
    // when the item saved successfully you can set the results to ok
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Duh, I should have thought of that. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

How about if you save a value to shared prefrances that would act as a flag : 
let us say the value is  x : 1 if it is changed and 0 if not.

By default it should be zero off course. whenever the user accesses the new activity and the contents of the database are changes the value should be changed back to 1. (If not it would stay zero).

Then onResume you check this value if it is zero then you do not re populate the list. However, if it is 1, you change it back to zero, update the list from the database, and call notifydatasetchanged() on the adapter.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `startActivityForResult()` and inform the calling activity whether or not data was changed.